Loss decreases but Neural network shows constant output
I trained neural network and cost function decreases with each update but the output is always constant, can someone help.
def forward_prop(x,w1,b1,w2,b2,w3,b3):
    Z1 = np.dot(w1,x.T) + b1
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
    Z2 = np.dot(w2,A1) + b2
    A2 = sigmoid(Z2)
    Z3 = np.dot(w3,A2) + b3
    A3 = sigmoid(Z3)
    cache = {'Z1':Z1,'A1':A1,'Z2':Z2, 'A2' : A2, 'Z3':Z3, 'A3':A3}
    return A3,cache
    
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_dir(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))
def prediction(x,W1,b1,W2,b2,W3,b3):
    A3,cache = forward_prop(x,W1,b1,W2,b2,W3,b3)
    return A3
    
def initialize_param(x,num_neuron_1 = 3,num_neuron_2 = 3,num_neuron_3 = 1):
    W1 = np.random.random((num_neuron_1,x.shape[1]))
    b1 = np.random.random((num_neuron_1,1))
    W2 = np.random.random((num_neuron_2, num_neuron_1))
    b2 = np.random.random((num_neuron_2,1))
    W3 = np.random.random((num_neuron_3,num_neuron_2))
    b3 = np.random.random((num_neuron_3,1))
    return W1,b1,W2,b2,W3,b3

def back_prop(cache,X,Y,W1,W2,W3):
    A1 = cache['A1']
    A2 = cache['A2']
    A3 = cache['A3']
    Z1 = cache['Z1']
    Z2 = cache['Z2']
    Z3 = cache['Z3']
    
    E3 = A3 - Y
    E2 = np.dot(W3.T,E3) * sigmoid_dir(Z2)
    E1 = np.dot(W2.T , E2) * sigmoid_dir(Z1)
    
    dW3 = np.dot(E3,A2.T) / X.shape[0]
    db3 = E3 / X.shape[0]
    dW2 = np.dot(E2,A1.T) / X.shape[0]
    db2 = E2 / X.shape[0]
    dW1 = np.dot(E1,X) / X.shape[0]
    db1 = E1 / X.shape[0]
    # print('dW1',dW1,'db1',db1,'dW2',dW2,'db2',db2,'dW3',dW3,'db3',db3 )
    return dW1,db1,dW2,db2,dW3,db3

    
def update_param(W1 , b1 , W2 , b2 , W3 , b3 , dW1,db1,dW2,db2,dW3,db3,lr = 0.01):
    W1 = W1 -  lr * dW1
    b1 = b1 -  lr * db1
    W2 = W2 -  lr * dW2
    b2 = b2 -  lr * db2
    W3 = W3 -  lr * dW3
    b3 = b3 -  lr * db3
    
    return W1,b1,W2,b2,W3,b3

def train(X,Y,epochs = 500000 ):
    W1,b1,W2,b2,W3,b3 = initialize_param(X)
    loss_values = []
    epoch_values = [] 
    X = X.to_numpy()
    X = (X - np.mean(X, axis=0)) / np.std(X, axis=0)
    Y = Y.to_numpy()
    Y = Y.reshape(1, -1)
    for i in range(epochs):
        A3 , cache = forward_prop(X,W1,b1,W2,b2,W3,b3)
        dW1,db1,dW2,db2,dW3,db3 = back_prop(cache,X,Y,W1,W2,W3)
        W1,b1,W2,b2,W3,b3 = update_param(W1 , b1 , W2 , b2 , W3 , b3 , dW1,db1,dW2,db2,dW3,db3,lr = 0.00005)
        
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            loss = -np.mean(Y * np.log(A3) + (1 - Y) * np.log(1 - A3))
            loss_values.append(loss)
            epoch_values.append(i)
            print(f"Epoch {i}, Loss: {loss}")
    plt.plot(epoch_values, loss_values)  # Plot loss vs epochs
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.title('Loss Curve')
    plt.show()
    return W1,b1.mean(axis=1),W2,b2.mean(axis=1),W3,b3.mean(axis=1)


Can you show how you use your functions and the result you get?

Yes , i run
W1,b1,W2,b2,W3,b3 = train(X,Y,epochs=10000)
The loss values are :
Epoch 0, Loss: 1.1331812791655305 Epoch 1000, Loss: 1.118617149513301 Epoch 2000, Loss: 1.1044111722152954 Epoch 3000, Loss: 1.09056006824168 Epoch 4000, Loss: 1.0770603198256694 Epoch 5000, Loss: 1.063908178234174 Epoch 6000, Loss: 1.0510996723619803 Epoch 7000, Loss: 1.0386306180867946 Epoch 8000, Loss: 1.0264966283174342 Epoch 9000, Loss: 1.014693123663282
But for each input
x = X_test.iloc[4]
prediction(x,W1,b1,W2,b2,W3,b3)
the output was array([0.75422397])

Please do not post such stuff in the comments; edit & update your post instead.
